# SQL query in bat file

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd

Is possible to execute this sql query in a bat file with osql command or similar?

```
-- STEP 1
TRUNCATE TABLE DatabaseTest..TableTest
-- STEP 2
USE [DatabaseTest]
DECLARE     @return_value int
EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[ReorgDatabase]
            @psysDbName = DatabaseTest,
            @psysLoginId = user,
            @psysPassword = password,
            @pvarLogFile = N'c:\Log'
SELECT      'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried it yourself and if so, please show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I know how to make 'select' and 'alter' sql querys with osql command, but the code of the top I have no idea how to use it in a osql sentence. I've tried much possibilities but any of them worked. I'm not sure about the use of variables in osql.

Comment: OK, so what *did* you try, and what results did you get?

Comment: I've tried among many others some like this. In this example i use $ instead of @

--STEP 1
osql -S ComputerName -U User -P password -Q "TRUNCATE TABLE DatabaseTest..TableTest"
--STEP 2
osql -S ComputerName -U User -P password -Q "USE DatabaseTest DECLARE $return_value int EXEC  $return_value = [dbo].[ReorgDatabase]  $psysDbName = DatabaseTest,  $psysLoginId = user,  $psysPassword = password,  $pvarLogFile = N'c:\Log'   SELECT      'Return Value' = $return_value"

I can't remember what errors I got, I'm not sure if I'm using the right sintax or if I have to use SELECT before EXEC.

Comment: Edit your attempt(s) into the  question and show the errors you get.

Comment: I cant post my errors because I need this query to use in my job and i cant wrote down the errors. Please if you know how to do this please tell me. I dont have much free time to find out how to do it.

Comment: Instead of `-Q "sql statements` use `-i "file.sql"` and put all the SQL in a single file.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that way. I'll try it as soon as I can.